# Magento2 admin panel product list page attribute is not showing in list

Tags: magento2

I added attributes like warehouse, shipping_charge,school,class in Product Attributes.

In listing ( i selected in filter options)
warehouse and shipping_charge is displaying.
school,class is not displaying.

all 4 entries are same Please help me on this.

Comment: Edit Attribute  Go to Storefront Properties & Check `Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront` & `Used in Product Listing` set to `Yes` or not?

Comment: I had already did this but not showing::

Comment: @Taslim Waris please re-index and clear the cache.

Comment: @AnkitShah ::  i did Scope=>store view
Add to Column Options=>YES
Use in Filter Options=>YES
Allow HTML Tags on Storefront=>YES
Used in Product Listing=>YES
ELSE PART IS NO NOW CLASS IS VISIBLE
SCHOOL STILL NOT DISPLAY

Answer (score 1):

Go to database set Is visible to 1

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET `is_visible` = '1' WHERE `catalog_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = YourAttributeId;
```